# Access AS/400 data base using JPA / Hibernate / JAVA on JBoss 7.1

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, ibm-midrange

## -ORIGINAL_POST-

I'm currently developing a JAVA (1.7) server application running on an JBoss 7. Using Spring and Hibernate this would be nothing unusual, but I have to connect an old AS/400 DB to the system. So far I've adjusted the drivers for the application server and the database connection has been established. The application server has logged that the database has beend found.

Now I've tried to access the data using JPA and Hibernate. But there seems to be a problem with my libraries. He is what the server is logging.

English:

> For this file no library has been found in the SQL/ODBC files. The
>   file was not found in the *CURLIB, *LIBL or the default library of the
>   data base source. There is no OVRDBF or a OVRDBF has not been set.
>   [...] PCSACC/400

German original:

> Für diese Datei wurde keine Bibliothek in den SQL/ODBC-Daten
>   ermittelt. Die Datei wurde nicht in der *CURLIB, *LIBL oder in der
>   Default-Bibliothek der Datenquelle gefunden. Es besteht kein OVRDBF
>   oder in einem OVRDBF wurde keine Bibliothek angegeben. [..] PCSACC/400

Is my assumption right and I have to add an additional library to my EAR in order to run the queries? Another scenario would be, that the AS/400 has to be accessed in a different way - perhaps the application has connected to the db but not to the instance I need to access.

One additional question - can I simulate this type of db?

## -EDIT_ONE-

The data source onfiguration of the JBoss 'urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0' subsystem:

```
<xa-datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/asdb" pool-name="asdb" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
  <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">192.168.1.666</xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="databaseName">A1B2C3D4</xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="Libraries">DMS7_0</xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="User">myuser</xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="Password">myuser</xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="naming">system</xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="translateBinary">true</xa-datasource-property>
  <xa-datasource-property name="errors">full</xa-datasource-property>
  <driver>com.ibm.as400</driver>
</xa-datasource>
```

And the possible drivers:

```
<drivers>
  <driver name="net.sourceforge.jtds" module="net.sourceforge.jtds">
    <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <xa-datasource-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
  </driver>
  <driver name="com.ibm.db2" module="com.ibm.db2">
    <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
  </driver>
  <driver name="com.ibm.as400" module="com.ibm.as400">
    <driver-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</driver-class>
    <xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
  </driver>
</drivers>
```

The Hibernate versions:

- Hibernate Core 3.6.9
- Hibernate JPA API 2.0

The JBoss-Web-Configuration for the data source

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/ASdb</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>java:/asdb</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Can you post fragments of your Hibernate config files that show your AS/400 (IBM i) connection as well as one or two of the files?  Specifically, I'm looking for the JDBC URL--feel free to mask your IP address/user/password to ensure privacy--and a <hibernate-mapping><class> spec for one or two of the DB2/400 tables.

Comment: I'm currently gathering all necessary informations.

Comment: are all tables in the DMS7_0 library?  In your <hibernate-mapping>, in the <class> tag, do you have a table="xxxxxx"?  Is the table name just the table name or does it specifcy a library/schema with a slash or a dot (like DMS7_0.MYTABLE or DMS7_0/MYTABLE or is it just MYTABLE)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that you're connecting to AS/400; those machines are decades old. However, your colleagues may still refer to it as this. The current OS is called IBM i, and this is important for internet searches to return modern results.

DB2 for i has two naming styles: SYSTEM and SQL.  It looks like this connexion is using SYSTEM naming.  Perhaps there's a way to change it to SQL naming so that the connexion uses the library/schema needed.

There is only one instance of DB2 on a given copy of IBM i.

What I do is to set the library list (SYSTEM naming) by way of the job description that the user profile is set up to use.  So connecting with user QA runs with the QA libraries, and the exact same client connecting with user PRODUCTION runs with the production libraries.  This is handled by the IBM i sysadmin.

You can almost simulate this DB if you load up DB2 LUW.  There are many similarities between DB2 for i and LUW.  But they are not identical!  On IBM i, I can write stored procedures, functions, and triggers in a HLL.  LUW only allows them to be written in SQL.  So 'moving' a copy from IBM i to Linux might be a lot of work.  And then there are the syntactical differences between them.  If the IBM i version is quite current (7.3 in Jan 2017) then you have a better chance of success.

Comment: The admin only told us that the connections could not be established, not that he had deleted the old database and created another one with a new name. But this posts gives are good insight and so I want to give credit to it by accepting it as an answer. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I usually have to reference the Library inside of the Datasource URL `jdbc:as400://{SERVERNAME}:{PORTNUMBER}/{LIBRARY}`.

However, you mention Hibernate, in which you may be using Entities. If you are using entities, I get a similar error on a completely different system (Tomcat, Jersey) unless I make sure to specify the table and Library (schema) inside of the entity itself:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLENAME", schema = "LIBRARYNAME")
@XmlRootElement
public class TextMessageList {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...
```